# Output is fetched from the first input provided in the textbox 3, but the output should be change dynamically based textbox 3 input

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

We have to provide input to three textbox. In two of the textbox, the value is static but the value is changed in the third one. Based on this input provided in the textbox, we click the Search button and the result is generated .E.g. Textbox1: 2, Textbox2: 3, Textbox3:91, Click on Search button. The page is refreshed for few seconds & output is generated. Total count: 13. Now againTextbox1: 2, Textbox2: 3, Textbox3:92,Click on Search button. The page is refreshed for few seconds & output is generated.Total count: 17.

But As per the below code, the output is 13.
please let me know issue in the code. I am not able to rectify it.

```
if (myFixedNumbers[0]==91){
 driver.findElement(By.id("txtPortal")).sendKeys(Integer.toString(myFixedNumbers[0]));
 driver.findElement(By.id("btnSearch")).click();
 // use it just before the sendkeys code like this
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//*[@id='dvCount']/span[2]")));
 String text1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='dvCount']/span[2]")).getText();
 System.out.println(text1);

 }

if (myFixedNumbers[1]==92){
 driver.findElement(By.id("txtPortal")).clear();
 driver.findElement(By.id("txtPortal")).sendKeys(Integer.toString(myFixedNumbers[1]));
 driver.findElement(By.id("btnSearch")).click();
 // use it just before the sendkeys code like this
 //wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//*[@id='dvCount']/span[2]")));
 String text2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='dvCount']/span[2]")).getText();
 System.out.println(text2);

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second if block the wait code is commented. Because of this the code will try to retrieve the value from the box without being wait till the page is loaded. So try to uncomment the wait statement and retrieve the value.

Comment: @Karthik- My Bad. It was by mistake commented. but its not working. Could you help me

Comment: @Roy - Can you please clarify that you are getting "Total Count: 17" on your screen or "Total Count: 13". If you are observing the earlier value, then it is an issue which we will look, but if you are getting later then there is some issue in the logic. Can you please clarify

Answer (score 0):

Hi try this it will work

```
if (myFixedNumbers[0] == 91) {
            driver.findElement(By.id("txtPortal")).sendKeys(Integer.toString(myFixedNumbers[0]));
            driver.findElement(By.id("btnSearch")).click();
            // use it just before the sendkeys code like this
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='dvCount']/span[2]")));
            String text1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='dvCount']/span[2]")).getText();
            System.out.println("Output 1 : " + text1);
        } 
        if (myFixedNumbers[1] == 92) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            driver.findElement(By.id("txtPortal")).clear();
            driver.findElement(By.id("txtPortal")).sendKeys(Integer.toString(myFixedNumbers[1]));
            driver.findElement(By.id("btnSearch")).click();
            // use it just before the sendkeys code like this
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='dvCount']/span[2]")));
            String text2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='dvCount']/span[2]")).getText();
            System.out.println("Output 2 : " + text2);
        }
```

Comment: its not working , same value is getting fetched again . the value which is fetched from the first iteration is again shown while iterating in the second one.

Comment: do one thing plz share the screen shot of the source code before first if and after second if

Answer (score 0):

I have inserted Thread.Sleep and removed wait code .it is working fine now.